# One way mirrored hollow sphere

Tags: visible-light, reflection

Imagine a one way mirror, where from one side it appears to be glass, but from the other side, it appears to be a mirror.

Now, fold that sheet into a hollow sphere, so the inside is mirror (and I'm talking standard mirror - nothing special about it), but the outside is glass. You would be able to see in, but not out.

What would this look like? What (if any) special properties would this have?

Comment: A one way mirror works because there is lower light on the non reflective side of the mirror than the other.  In a sphere, you would not have that.  I expect you'd be able to look through the ball without a problem.  Its properties being similar to a glass sphere.

Comment: Ok, any amendments I can make to make this question answerable? Like, I don't know, a light inside the sphere & have it in a darkened room?

Comment: One way mirrors don't actually exist.  Light leaks both directions.  That's how you can see through the mirror from the "back" -- light leaked out.

Comment: Your folding description to fold a flat sheet into a sphere also can't be done but I suppose we can ignore the geometry aspect of the question.

Comment: I guess they do not exist yet, but could be made in the future using some nonlinear photonic cristal. They recently created a photonic diode.

Comment: @BrandonEnright I was using "folding" as simplification. BTW I'm aiming for this more to be a discussion.

Comment: If you're imagining an object that allows light falling on it to enter (or be absorbed) and not to leave (or be emitted), then it would appear black.

Comment: You should rephrase your question. Partially reflective mirror, illuminated object on the inside. What would an observer inside see and what would an observer outside in a darkened room see. It's a good question and without building it I can't imagine the answer. I have seen decorative art displays where there are two mirrors, one a partial reflector - face to face. And between the two some array of lights. What appears to the observer outside is an infinite tunnel of lights. Quite impressive. So if you do the same with a sphere?

Comment: @julianfenandez: even a non-linear photonic crystal can't get around thermodynamics, unless it is powered by something. Such a powered one-way mirror does exist, of course. It's usually called closed circuit tv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as interesting an idea as this is, and as creative as you must be for thinking of it, it's not an actual possibility as far as I'm concerned.

A one-way mirror works much in the same way that a metallic screen door works. It allows you to see from the inside of your house, outward. However, this is due to the fact that there is far more sunlight and it is far brighter than inside your house. At night, the opposite effect is true; neighbors can watch whatever you're doing inside your house, but you cannot see out.

The reason is that there is plenty of light outside to reflect off of the surface during the day; so much so that you don't notice the small amount of light coming out.

Again, an interesting idea, but optics has its way out of this conundrum.